Server allows remote access but not local login
I'm working on a shared server that runs Ubuntu 22.04.5
As of yesterday, I and other users (most of whom have admin privileges) have been able to log in remotely via ssh, but cannot log in locally from the terminal itself. When I attempt to log in locally, I get a black screen, and a few second later am returned to the login prompt with no error message.
I found a thread where a user had a similar but not identical problem -
Local Ubuntu desktop cannot login after opened Xrdp session
i.e. being unable to log in locally if he was also logged in remotely, but in my case, I'm simply unable to log in locally whether I'm concurrently logged in remotely or not.
Because several users have multi-day processes running, I'm not able to try a simple fix of a restart to see if the problem self-resolves. Can anyone suggest things that I can try via remote access to trouble-shoot and possibly fix this in the meantime? I'm wondering what could be causing the problem to begin with - the logins are authenticated according to the system log, but the user interface fails to load.

Since you are using a server, I assume it does not have any desktop GUI. So the problem with xrdp does not apply in your situation. Could you copy and paste the parts of the system log in your question? Format the pasted log as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.
